# Merge two .htaccess files from two projects into one

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a project which I have to include within a project.
So .. project A is a web site built on top of custom framework which uses this .htaccess rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

The second project B is built on top of another custom framework and I am supposed to make it look like a subfolder to the first one.
So I placed project B inside a folder "subfolder". Project B has its own .htaccess which looks like this:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$    index.php?request=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING}    [NE,L]

I want to merge them into a single .htacess file and tell to Apache something like :

if we have a parameter /subfolder redirect everything to subfolder/index.php

else redirect everything to index.php

Any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: When I try to keep both .htaccess files and change RewriteBase in the second one to RewriteBase /subfolder I get 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're supposed to do is:

For the first project, this htaccess file is in the document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Then in the second project, this htaccess file is in the `subfolder` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,QSA]
```

If for some reason that's not working for you, I guess a combined htaccess file, one that resides in the document root, would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for 2nd project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder/(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?request=$1 [NE,L,QSA]

# for 1st project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Will probably need a bit more tweaking.

Comment: I tried this but I forgot (.*)$ in the rewrite rule for the 2nd project and this messed up everything.
Thanks for the help !