# All rules from .htacess on one place

Tags: .htaccess

```
/
    www\
        \animals
            .htacess
        .htacess
```

First `.htacess` in `www` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !^.*on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.com/$1 [R,L]
```

And I have to have for each project (like `animals`) the same `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /animals/

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !^.*on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.com/animals/$1 [R,L]
```

Is there any possibility to have all rules just in *main* `.htacess` in `www` folder?

Comment: Yes , you can have all the rules in  single .htacess file in root www folder. You might want to refer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825018/merge-two-htaccess-files-from-two-projects-into-one

Comment: Yeah, I know about that. I tried it, but without any success. May you help me, please?

Comment: Make help _possible_. Show the code you tried, and give us a _proper_ problem description - “without success” isn’t one. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).